# Get particular object from association with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have next association for user:

```
has_many :sent_requests, foreign_key: :requester_id, class_name: 'FriendRequest'
```

Here is FriendRequest model:

```
class FriendRequest < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :requester, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :target, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I include this association when query requests.

I want to get request to particular user if it exists. Next approach initiates request to the DB:

```
  def friend_request_sent_to(user)
    self.sent_requests.where(target: user).first
  end
```

I need to call this method for the list of user. How can I get request to user from self without going to database on every call?

Comment: Could you be more specific? How do you want this method to be executed against a list? What is to be returned? (an Array of results, hash, Ar objects with extra field?)

Comment: I want to get FriendRequest sent by user to another user that is in params. On the list of users I want to show statuses of this Requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ActiveRecord caching (please be aware of this)

You should be aware that ActiveRecord automatically caches associations. If you evaluate `self.sent_requests` twice, only one database query will be executed (note, there are some caveats).

That means you can use Enumerable methods multiple times and the association will only be loaded once.  E.g.

```
self.sent_requests.find { |friend_request|  friend_request.target == user }
```

Note that this will not work if you add additional calls to AR query interface methods, like `sent_requests.where(...)`, or `sent_requests.joins(...)`.

Also, ActiveRecord [caches query results](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching). So executing `self.sent_requests.where(target: user).first` multiple times may only result in a single database query.

### Memoization

You can also use memoization as suggested by another user. The tricky part about memoizing results is handling `nil` or `false` cases. There is a nice [gem](https://github.com/dkubb/memoizable) which handles this for you.

An unsophisticated approach with memoization which avoids nil issues:

```
class User
  has_many :sent_requests, foreign_key: :requester_id, class_name: 'FriendRequest'

  def friend_request_sent_to(user)
    @sent_requests ||= self.sent_requests.includes(:user).to_a  # Will always result in an Array (no need to worry about nil)
    @sent_requests.find {|sent_request| sent_request.user == user }
  end
```

This method also has the advantage of allowing you to use more complex queries which would not be cached by ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the result in instance variable:

```
def friend_request_sent?(user)
  return @friend_request_sent if defined?(@friend_request_sent)
  @friend_request_sent = self.sent_requests.where(target: user).first
end
```

Also note that it is a ruby convention for methods ending with `?` to return true or false. Most likely you rather want to do:

```
def friend_request_sent?(user)
  return @friend_request_sent if defined?(@friend_request_sent)
  @friend_request_sent = self.sent_requests.exists?(target: user)
end
```

Comment: But if I call this method for list of users it will still be a lot of requests

Comment: Those two lines could be easily reduced to one, as well `@friend_request_sent ||= self.sent_requests.exists?(target: user)`

Comment: @theTRON - They cannot. `||=` will execute right side even if the expression has been evaluated but resulted in nil or false.

Comment: @theTRON I think the problem with `@friend_request_sent ||= ...` is that if the  sent_requests doesn't exist, the database call is still attempted.  It only minimises db calls if a record was found, not if it wasn't found. BrioSatse answer avoids this problem.

Comment: Oh, of course! Silly me. Yes, you're both quite right. :)

Comment: @earsonheart - In you rquestion youa re only saying about one model. Could you please update it so it is clear what you need?

Comment: Updated according to comments